# Why do some grasshoppers have a black exoskeleton?

Tags: evolution, species-identification, entomology

What species of grasshoppers have black exoskeletons? Is there a scientific difference in species between field crickets and grasshoppers?

Comment: where have you looked for this answer so far? have you done any work?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Right now it's very vague. Are you asking: "what species of grasshoppers are black?" If so, you should provide your location, size of the insect you're interested in, and preferably a picture of the grasshopper. Without these, your question is far too broad and likely will be closed.

Comment: Further, we typically ask that you perform (and demonstrate) some type of effort to answer your question on your own. For more details, please see [How to ask a good question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on the help page

Comment: So is your question about identifying species or wondering why evolution has caused some grasshoppers (or field crickets) to be black in color?

Answer (score 2):

[Field crickets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_cricket) are rather distinct from [grasshoppers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grasshopper). Although both groups are in the Order *Orthoptera*, grasshoppers are insects of the suborder *Caelifera* and field crickets are in the family *Gryllidae* of the suborder *Ensifera*.

For a discussion on insect coloraiton, see [here](http://what-when-how.com/insects/coloration-insects/).

If you'd like a specific species ID, please provide more information as requested in the comments.

Generally, field crickets are [black, red or brown](http://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.asp?identification=Field-Cricket) in color.

[image]

However, some species of grasshoppers are likewise black:

- For example: *Romalea* species such as [*R. microptera*](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/orn/lubber.htm) and dark nymphs and morphs of [*R. guttata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romalea_guttata)

[image: R. microptera]

Finally, [here](https://www.amentsoc.org/insects/fact-files/orders/orthoptera.html) is a simple checklist of some typical differences between grasshoppers and crickets.